# Post count by Parent Category

Tags: posts

I want to show post count in my site by parent category.

Example -
We have 18 Tutorials, 15 Article, 3 Freebies

Answer (score 1):

Here we'll use the function - [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to grab all the available categories and store it as array, Then we'll loop through the array to display the list. Within the foreach loop we did a conditional check that is to determine if category is parent if so print it.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories();
    echo 'We have ';
    foreach($categories as $category) 
    { 
        //to check if category is parent
        if ($category->parent==0)
        {
            echo $category->count . ' '; 
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">'. $category->name . '</a> , '; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

go here..you will find answer

http://jhherren.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/getting-the-number-of-posts-per-category-in-wordpress/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: Answers should be more than links...